# Why Humanity is more expendable than Earth?

Tags: hard-sci-fi

I seem to encounter many litreture ( where mostly Advanced AI's or Alie'sn decide) that Humanity must be annihilated in order to save Earth.

Even though Earth is really unique (with radiative cluster, giant moon, appropriate distance from right class star etc.) to let evolution and there may not be a second one (?) among 'Earth like' planets, I can't help to think that an intelligent life form such as Humans should not be more common than Earth.

And since many choose to kill Humanity rather than Earth in their work my question is: Is really Humanity more expendable then Earth scientifically or is it just to create a melodrama of  justified punishment of our greedy nature and discovering/showing ourselves that we are more than that?

PS: Not sure if this question is more fit here than a science based network.

Comment: Not sure if any SE site is suitable for this question. But there's plenty of people down my local boozer that will happily discuss this with you after a few pints.

Comment: There are so many, and question is more like is the idea belongs to fiction or science.

Comment: Very good question.+1. I think AI programmers train AI’s to find solution to global warming or how to make Earth a better place. There is only one large scale solution to make Earth a better place...

Comment: @atayenel - It's a good question, but a terrible fit for SFF:SE. Questions about the tendencies of real-world science fiction writers aren't on-topic here.

Comment: Life has a tendency to obliterate itself, see for example the microorganisms who poisoned themselves with oxygen (GOE). In fact, humanity might be the only species that has at least the possibility actively work against that. If humanity goes away, earth will have plants and animal life for a while before these die out and leave only microorganisms behind, long before the sun destroys earth.

Comment: @Valorum why? You have a tag of hard-science-fiction where you discuss if ideas are  enoung scientific or not?

Comment: Per the [FAQ]; *"If your question is about...Writing science fiction or fantasy, ask on Writers Stack Exchange."*.

Comment: Also, the 'science' tag is not intended as an invitation for idle chit-chat about why scifi writer tend to select certain tropes.

Comment: @Valorum I am not asking their tendencies or if this is science fiction or fantasy. I am asking if there is a real life science (hard-science) in these genre of work which I doubt that you can say it is not science-fiction. If it will please you, I can add Singulariy, Earth Stood Still etc. as tags.

Comment: Every thinking entity places subjective values on stuff. They are not even constant in time and situational. Some might put a higher "price tag" on earth, some on humanity. This question cannot be answered and I don't believe it is on-topic anywhere. I advice you to read some basic economic theory btw.

Comment: @atayenel This is a really good approach too. Thank you.

Comment: @Valorum you are right 'science' tag does not fit. Unfortunately in mobile I can't see details of tags. As also you can say this may not fit here but still will be waiting for comments to help.

Comment: @Valorum this question might be suitable for worldbuilding with a little editing. *Why my AI prefers human extinction rather than earth ?* kind of editing

Comment: @atayenel - As written, it'd get closed on WB almost immediately. It's too vague and too poorly written

Comment: @atayenel Thats what I was thinking. Will post there too with some paraphrasing.

Comment: There it goes https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/97858/under-what-circumstances-earth-is-more-expendable-then-humanity

Comment: What literature? Skynet felt threatened by humanity. HAL, was just... crazy? President Eden was programed that way. - It's up to you; you're the one writing the story.